# carrier wave Image upload gives different params from IE and different params in Firefox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, carrierwave

===================IE params Inside Create method=========>

```
params = {"qqfile"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0xf6064e0 @original_filename="Koala.jpg", @content_type="image/pjpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"qqfile\"; filename=\"Koala.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/pjpeg\r\n", @tempfile=#<File:/tmp/RackMultipart20111221-1749-kqb8za>>, "photo"=>{"pending"=>"true", "aspect_ids"=>{"0"=>"3", "1"=>"4"}}, "set_profile_image"=>"", "action"=>"create", "controller"=>"photos"}
```

===================Firefox params Inside Create method=========>

```
params = {"photo"=>{"pending"=>"true", "aspect_ids"=>{"0"=>"1", "1"=>"2"}}, "set_profile_image"=>"", "qqfile"=>"social_network.png", "action"=>"create", "controller"=>"photos"}
```

That means in IE the params[:qqfile] gives a "Class" and in Firefox params[:qqfile] gives a "String"

Any idea in Why is this happening and how i can fix this?

Comment: Just to check: this is being uploaded from a form that's set to use `multipart/form-data`, yes?